# List Drop Down Glitch?

Tags: list, dropdown

I just recently changed a choice in one of drop down list in my list settings (Red to Yellow).
When I clicked ok and went to view my list, **ALL** my entries are gone.  Is this a glitch?  I mean a major glitch?

Comment: That has never been my experience. Some more details are needed... SharePoint version, anything unique about the list or the column? (customizations, custom formatting, etc.)

Comment: @mike-smith-mct-mvp, thanks for replying.  I'm on SharePoint 2013.  However, now, it's working.  I'm not sure what happened?  The only thing is that I requested for my list to be saved as a template and I didn't know they were doing it the time I was experiencing the issue (I don't have permissions to save a list as a template so I have to submit a ticket to request it).  Could that have been related?  Maybe I was looking at the new list?  Not sure how templates work but all I know it's working now.